# JavaScript: Try/Catch vs error function passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, conceptual

I am wondering which approach is better for error handling and debugging in **JavaScript** for **nodeJS**?

Having a pure try/catch block:

```
try
{
  dangerous.function();

}
catch(error);
{
  console.log(error);
}
```

or

Just using a function as a parameter, which will display if any errors occur

```
dangerous.function(function(error)
{
  console.log(error);
});
```

I am raising this question because I read that try/throw has a potential of logging too much stack trace data as written here: http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors

Comment: Well, the main limitations of native `try/catch`  is that it's not typed (you have to either catch _everything_ or _nothing_ and that it doesn't work with asynchronous functions (in Node you can work around that with domains, or even better - just use promises which are throw safe). If those two are not concerns prefer native syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aimed to fulfill the same purpose, but they are to be used in different contexts:

- try/catch will only work to intercept synchronous errors
- callback will allow both synchronous and asynchronous errors transmission

I strongly advice to read [this article](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) (even though it is first addressed for Node.js developers, it is valuable for every JavaScript developer) which fully covers the subject.

Answer (score 4):

It's totally up to you. Exceptions have the advantage of providing a stack trace.

Note that if `dangerous.function` does its work *asynchronously*, then you'll need to use your second approach, since there isn't any exception to catch initially. But that doesn't mean you can't use an exception, just that if you want to use an exception, you have to *pass* the exception to the callback rather than throwing it. (Or don't use an exception, that's also totally up to you.)

Comment: ---You don't _actually_ have to pass an exception to the callback - you can use promises.--- meh that was snarky. Overall good answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You can use promises, but the result of the promise (which you'd be passing to the promise's reject callback) can be an exception with the handy info. The phrasing of my last sentence can be improved, though, I'm on it.

Comment: Yes, as long as those are `Error` objects (or use `Error.captureStackTrace` explicitly) you get stack traces. People tend to underestimate those in JavaScript for some reason until they have an error in a 100K LoC code base at which point they panic :)